# capture Multiple Pictures in one CameraCaptureTask Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

Is it possible to capture Multiple Pictures in one CameraCaptureTask using Windows Phone ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two solutions here

1. Easy to implement (but not great from UX point of view)

   Trigger new CameraCaptureTask.Show on CameraCaptureTask.Completed until you got required number of pictures.
2. Implementing own MultipleCameraCaptureTask

   [Using Cameras in Your Windows Phone Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708750.aspx)

   [Windows Phone samples for Camera and Photos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_CameraAndPhotos)

You can also take a look how CameraCaptureTask is implemented using reflector; there is a chance you will be able to re-use some classes/ui.